# Mechanism for asynchronous loading of external applet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have adsense on one of my sites and a typical page may contain something like this on its html:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 2009Menu -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:120px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>


<div align="center">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 2009Vertical -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

This thing is making the page takes a huge time to load.... typically 6 seconds. Without it, the page loads in 0.5 seconds!!!!!!!

And in theory this ad is already being served asynchronously (ha!)

And the page is not displayed until everything is loaded (!?)

Is there any mechanism to make this load asynchronous using javascript, css or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `async` use `defer`. With `defer` tag script won't run until page loads!
Something like this :

```
<script src="source/to/script" defer></script>
```